# Symfony - prohibit communication in migration, Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony5

I want to forbid the doctrine to build FK in columns, since communications will be carried out at the code level, and the exhaust from it interferes with development. Is it possible to implement this?

```
/**
     * @var Product
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Product",
     *      inversedBy="warehouse",
     *      orphanRemoval=true,
     *      cascade={"persist", "remove"}
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private ?Product $product;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it!
Generate table, and relations in migrate, deleted relation with id=id add table name in doctrine.dbal.connections.default.schema_filter and now I have relation for many table by id=id, and Doctrine not now parse join, it's not good, but it's helps me.